# INSTEAD OF UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT : determine each command

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, updating

I need determine each of this this 3 commands in trigger [UPDATE,DELETE,INSERT].For last 2 I do next:

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted)
      BEGIN 

      END
    ELSE IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
      BEGIN 

      END
```

How can I get updating rows?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. You create the trigger `FOR UPDATE` in the first place, so all rows in `inserted` are updated, with their old copies in `deleted`.

Comment: I want first: determine UPDATE command , second:get access to rows that will update existing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're trying to accomplish, but you can test if it's an `UPDATE` if *both* `inserted` (values *after* update) and `deleted` (values *before* update) exist. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx):

> The **deleted** table stores copies of the affected rows during DELETE
>   and **UPDATE** statements. During the execution of a DELETE or UPDATE
>   statement, rows are deleted from the trigger table and transferred to
>   the deleted table. The deleted table and the trigger table ordinarily
>   have no rows in common.
>
> The **inserted** table stores copies of the affected rows during
>   INSERT and **UPDATE** statements. During an insert or update
>   transaction, new rows are added to both the inserted table and the
>   trigger table. The rows in the inserted table are copies of the new
>   rows in the trigger table.

Thus, if `inserted` exists but not `deleted`, it's an `INSERT`; if `deleted` exists but not `inserted`, it's a `DELETE`; if they both exist, it's an `UPDATE`.